# About native-activity in android

Tags: android

In Ginger-bread  new feature is added like `native-activity`.

`Native-activity` has its own life-cycle.

Is there any feasibility  to draw our own button and to take the event out
for performing action in the native code itself.As per example given by android
developer site  -which is based on animation using OpenGL is working fine.But I want
what type of further experiment can be done.